# MAUI : Android : Building failed in Rider

Tags: android, maui, rider

While building solution gives below issue in Rider

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/32.0.485/tools/Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(79,5): error : java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/abc/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture/1.0.0.11/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/guava-listenablefuture.jar : com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.class [/Users/abc/xyz/xyz1.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]

Can someone suggest any pointers to solve this ?